# How to run JavaScript function in WooCommerce checkout?

Tags: javascript, woocommerce-offtopic, captcha

I'm building reCAPATCHA into my WooCommerce checkout. It is a fairly easy process as I'm using `woocommerce_checkout_process` to validate the capatcha. However, I have running into one issue.

When there is a cart error, I want to be able to reset the reCAPATCHA using `grecaptcha.reset();` JavaScript function. I'm unsure how to run the JavaScript command upon cart error in WooCommerce. Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not been able to figure out how to inject JavaScript upon cart error. However, I am using a workaround -- `setInterval` at WooCommerce checkout that looks for an error message, and then calls `grecaptcha.reset();`

Comment: That is really not a good solution. The proper way is just like @Sgaddo said, to bind the "checkout_error" event. If it's not triggering for you, then you probably don't have it in the right place

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same need, because of the ajax checkout validation.

Woocommerce has some custom javascript events we can hook to. 
In reCaptcha specific case we need to hook to `checkout_error` that is triggered when the ajax call fails.

So, I solved with the following code in my own javascript file, besides the PHP custom validation hooked to `woocommerce_checkout_process`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( document.body ).on( 'checkout_error', function() {
        grecaptcha.reset();
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!